# Нужна ли запятая после "душить друг друга"?

Tags: запятые

*Она обладает мощной корневой системой, и если загустить посадки, то растения вскоре начнут душить друг друга и цветение ослабеет.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятая не нужна, поскольку последняя часть тоже относится к придаточному (если загустить посадки, то цветение ослабеет). Как результат того, что растения душат друг друга, но всё равно при таком условии.